# How to make a PictureBox fill a UserControl while being adjusted in the designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, picturebox

Technology: .NET 4, C#, WinForms, Visual Studio 2010

I have run into an issue when sizing a custom `UserControl`. The customer `UserControl` simply contains a `PictureBox` with the properties set such that scroll bars appear when necessary.

The `UserControl` has the following properties set:

- AutoScaleMode: Font
- AutoScroll: True
- DoubleBuffered: True
- MinimumSize: 100, 100
- Size: 250, 250

The `PictureBox` has the following properties set:

- Anchor: Top, Left
- Location: 0,0
- Size: 250, 250
- SideMode: AutoSize

In the designer view for the custom control, the `PictureBox` fills the entire like is desired. However,  in the designer view for the main application, the custom `UserControl` is initally 250 x 250 like its designer showed, but when I resize it to fit in the main application, only the `UserControl` panel is resized leaving the `PictureBox` to the originl 250 x 250. One of the properties I expose is the mouse cursor X,Y position inside the `PictureBox` and when there is no image loaded, the property returns nothing outside of the 250 x 250 area.

I have tried:

- Setting the Anchor property to Top, Left, Right, Bottom, but that causes the `UserControl` not to display scroll bars.
- Setting the Dock property of the `PictureBox` to fill, but that also results in `UserControl` not display scroll bars.

How can I make it such that the `PictureBox` is always the full size of the `UserControl`, even when being adjusted in the designer?

Comment: Why you need to display scoll bars if PictureBox fills the UserControl?

Comment: Yes, I can see how this wasn't clear. In the main application, the PictureBox will typically be larger than UserControl and thus will have scroll bars. My problem is that when the main application launches, the PictureBox is the size it was created in the designer no matter what size the UserControl is at the moment. It no longer fills the UserControl as is desired.

Comment: You have set the `SizeMode` property of the picture box to `AutoSize`, so when you set an image in the `Image` property of the picture box, the picture box should resize itself to match the size of the image. Did you set the `Image` property?

Comment: When I set the `PictureBox` to an image larger than the `UserControl`, it works as expected. I'm trying to solve the situation when the `UserControl` is loaded for the first time and is an unknown size, yet the `PictureBox` is still the size I set it as in the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need scrollbars on the user control so when the user control is smaller than the picture shown in the picurebox, the user can scroll the to see other parts of the picture, right? And also when the user control is larger than the picture box, you want that the picture box to fill the user control (so you cant catch mouse events on the picture box). Right?

First of all, you can also subscribe to the mouse event on the user control (in addition to the picture box) to do the desired action. If that's not applicable, you can do this:

Handle the Resize event of the user control, and change the aspects of the picture box:

(put this in your user control)

```
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        MaintainPictureBoxSize();
    }

    private void MaintainPictureBoxSize()
    {
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;

        pictureBox1.Location = new Point();
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size();

        var clientSize = this.ClientSize;

        if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
            pictureBox1.Size = clientSize;
        else
        {
            Size s = pictureBox1.Image.Size;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(
                clientSize.Width > s.Width ? clientSize.Width : s.Width,
                clientSize.Height > s.Height ? clientSize.Height : s.Height);
        }
    }
```

Also call the `MaintainPictureBoxSize` method when you change the `Image` of the `PictureBox`.
The effect of this is, when width or height of the image being shown in the picture box is smaller than the user control, the picture box will expand to fill the user control, and if not, the size of the picture box is the size of the image, so scrollbars are shown.

Comment: I tried your code snippet and it caused the scroll bars to always be drawn if no image is loaded when the `PictureBox` should be the same size as the `UserControl`.

Comment: That caused some odd behavior. Initially, there are no scroll bars present. When I increase the size of the form (before any image has been loaded), there are still no scroll bars present. However, when I decrease the size of the form (even from maximized), scroll bars appear and stay until I resize to a larger size again.

Comment: I've modified the code again. I've tested this one, and it worked with no problem (except some flickers while resizing).